# Sobre encadeamento de métodos. Por que está dando nullPointerException?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, nullpointerexception

Tenho a classe Pedido:

```
package teste;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

   public class Pedido {
     List<Item> lista = new ArrayList<Item>();;
     Cliente cliente;

     public Pedido adicionarPedido(int quantidade, String nome){

       lista.add(new Item(nome, quantidade));
       return this;
     }

     public Pedido paraOCliente(String nome){
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente(nome);
        return this;
     }

       public void fechar(){
           System.out.println("Nome " + this.cliente.getNome() + " " +  lista.get(0));
       }
}
```

A classe Cliente:

```
package teste;

   public class Cliente {

     private String nome;

     public String getNome() {
        return nome;
     }

     public void setNome(String nome) {
       this.nome = nome;
     }

     public Cliente(String nome){
       this.nome = nome;
     }
}
```

A classe Item:
    package teste;

```
   public class Item {

      private String nomeProduto;
      private int quantidade;

      public Item(String nome, int quantidade){
        this.nomeProduto = nome;
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
      }
  }
```

E a classe Main:

```
package teste;

    public class Teste {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Pedido().adicionarPedido(1, "tênis schutz")
                 .adicionarPedido(2, "iphone 7")
                 .paraOCliente("Aline Gonzaga")
                 .fechar(); 
    }
}
```

Está dando esse problema:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at teste.Pedido.fechar(Pedido.java:21)
at teste.Teste.main(Teste.java:10)
```

Alguém poderia me dizer qual o problema eu não consigo ver onde está...

Comment: Eu vejo meio com maus olhos essa forma de utilizar o recurso, me soa como abuso de seu uso.

Comment: ??????????????????

Comment: O @diegofm tem toda razão, minha resposta fala disto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque a variável `cliente` não foi inicializada. A solução paliativa deve ser algo assim:

```
Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
```

O ideal é que a classe `Cliente` fosse feita de outra forma, mas isso é outro problema. A classe `Pedido` também permite que esse tipo de coisa aconteça. O ideal é que o objeto nunca esteja em estado inválido. Para isso [existe o construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Esse método além de não fazer o que deseja, não é adequado, porque o objeto só funciona se ele for chamada:

```
public Pedido paraOCliente(String nome){
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente(nome);
    return this;
}
```

Assim funciona, mas continua criando um problema de *design* da classe:

```
public Pedido paraOCliente(String nome){
    cliente = new Cliente(nome);
    return this;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/MethodChain.java).

Está tentando usar um padrão que não é adequado para esse caso. É o que eu sempre falo, seguir regras sem saber o porquê. Use o construtor para ter um objeto correto. Deixar os membros serem inicializados em partes é pedir para ter vários problemas. Se não arrumar isso o erro poderá continuar acontecendo. E como provavelmente não será testado em condições falhas (quase nenhum programador faz isso, as pessoas querem apenas ver funcionando) o erro só será detectado tarde demais, já que ele não aparecerá de cara.

Comment: No caso o `Cliente` está sobrando, tinha que ser `cliente = new Cliente();` ou `this.cliente = new Cliente();`

Comment: @Sorack eu não tinha terminado a resposta.

Comment: Susse, eu vi depois e dei +1 já ^^

Comment: Nossa voccê deu um tapa na minha cara. Rs. ok

Comment: @gonz não, mas você quer aprender ou fazer errado?

Comment: eu quero aprender né.....ok.

Answer (score 4):

```
public Pedido paraOCliente(String nome){
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente(nome);
    return this;
 }
```

deveria ser

```
  public Pedido paraOCliente(String nome){
        this.cliente = new Cliente(nome);

    return this;
 }
```