# Como faço para exibir o que está dentro da lista?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho esse método que adiciona coisas na lista:

```
 public Pedido adicionarPedido(int quantidade, String nome){

        lista.add(new Item(quantidade, nome ));
            return this;
 }
```

E instanciei nessa classe nos atributos a lista :

```
List<Item> lista = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Eu estou pedindo para exibir no método toString os dados da lista mais o nome da pessoa:

```
     public Pedido ToString() {
        mensagem = "Pedido [lista=" + lista.get(0) +  lista.get(1) + ", cliente=" + cliente.getNome() + "]";
          return this;
     }
```

O problema é que no console está sendo impresso assim:

```
Pedido [lista=teste.Item@15db9742 teste.Item@6d06d69c, cliente=Aline Gonzaga]
```

Mas eu quero que seja impresso os itens da lista.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Como está sua classe Pedido?

Comment: O que deveria imprimir? e reforço o pedido para postar a classe `Pedido`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua classe `Item` precisa sobrescrever o método `toString`. Por padrão o método mostra um `hashing` único gerado pelo `JDK`. Então ficaria algo do tipo:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return String.valueOf(this.getQuantidade()) + " " + this.getNome();
}
```

Sempre que um método que recebe uma `String` como parâmetro e um objeto é passado, o método `toString` é invocado. No caso de uma lista, o método de seus itens é invocado, causando o efeito que você descreveu *(Item@...)*.

Logo após você pode sobrescrever também o método da classe pedido:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "Pedido: lista=" + this.getLista() + ", cliente=" + this.getCliente().getNome();
}
```

Assim a seguinte chamada:

```
System.out.println(pedido);
```

Irá produzir:

```
Pedido: lista=[1 Produto 1, 2 Produto 2], cliente=Aline Gonzaga
```

Notei também que você usou o método `ToString` com letra maiúscula. Pela convenção de código `Java` os métodos devem iniciar com letra minúscula, com exceção dos construtores. Então você deveria sobrescrever o método `toString`.

Quanto a utilização e sugestão sobre o uso abusivo do `toString` [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165731/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-exibir-o-que-est%C3%A1-dentro-da-lista/165741#165741), temos [esse tópico no stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867269/when-should-i-override-tostring) que indica que a utilização é interessante para fins de depuração, então talvez para mostrar uma mensagem final na sua aplicação seja melhor outro método para definir a mensagem.

Comment: Acessar propriedades diretamente? E não é endereço de memória, é um hashing unico gerado pelo JDK.

Comment: Este é o problema de responder perguntas antes do OP adicionar maiores esclarecimentos. Falta informação na resposta.

Comment: Funcionou obrigada amigo

Comment: Agora vc poderia me explicar o motivo de ter dado certo, tipo só adicionei o ToString() na classe Item e funcionou...

Comment: Ótimo, obrigada. entendi.

Answer (score 4):

Pra mim é um abuso usar o `ToString()` para isso, esse método não foi criado para esse tipo de coisa.

Você deve pegar o elemento e o membro da classe, e deve fazer isso varrendo toa a lista, algo assim:

```
public Pedido ToString() {
     mensagem = "Pedido do Cliente " + cliente.getNome() + "\n";
     for (Item item : lista) mensagem += "Quantidade: " + item.quantidade + " Produto: " + item.nomeProduto + "\n";
     return this;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/PrintItems.java).

Só consegui responder olhando sua [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165453/101). Todo esse código ainda tem vários outros problemas.

Comment: Eu também  acho um abuso encadear métodos dessa forma, aparentemente sem necessidade, fazendo retornarem a propria classe, mas é a escolha do OP, só nos resta alertar mesmo.

Comment: @diegofm de fato tem isso também, mas já falei em outra resposta.

Comment: aprendi isso com minha professora. Bringuem com ela. rs

Comment: @gonz manda ela vir aqui, eu acho pouco provável que ela esteja ensinando errado, mas se estiver ela pode justificar porque está fazendo isso, ou aprender fazer direito.

Comment: @gonz só porque ela é professora não significa que seja dona da razão, já vi professores ensinarem do jeito que eles acham certo, mas depois vi que não era bem assim. Temos que ter a mente aberta para o conhecimento, e não nos engessar nas ideias que nos impoem, dessa forma, nós conseguimos obter um leque maior de recursos, independente de que linguagem ou área que se trate.