# Como exibir objetos de uma lista?

Tags: java, hibernate, arraylist

Tenho a classe PessoaDAO que tem o seguinte método:

```
public List<Pessoa> BuscarTodos() {

    List<Pessoa> list = null;

    EntityManager em = getEM();

    try {

        list = em.createQuery("select t from Pessoa t").getResultList();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());

    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

    return list;

}
```

E no meu Servlet, tenho o seguinte doGet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PessoaDAO<Pessoa> db = new PessoaDAO<Pessoa>();

    try {

    List<Pessoa> list = db.BuscarTodos();
    req.setAttribute("list", list);

    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);

    System.out.println(req.getAttribute("list"));

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Por que quando dou um sysout, ele aparece assim:

> [model.Pessoa@7d5d4b78, model.Pessoa@1eb15301, model.Pessoa@15f8c5af]

E não a lista propriamente dita?

Se ajudar, essa é classe pessoa:

```
@Entity 
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="NOME")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name="CPF")
    private String cpf;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }


}
```

Comment: Provável duplicata de [Como faço para exibir o que está dentro da lista?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165731/28595)

Comment: Mais uma: [Dúvidas sobre o método toString() da classe Object](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10893/28595)

Comment: Show.. já consegui as respostas nesses links.. muito obrigado!

Answer (score -3):

Quando você faz esse SELECT pelo hibernate, ele cria um objeto para linha do seu banco de dados. Esses valores que aparecem são o endereço que esse objeto está alocado no sua memória. Quando você manda imprimir o objeto, ele imprimi o endereço e não os dados daquele objeto. Você pode sobrescrever o método toString() para imprimir os dados da maneira que quiser.

Comment: Não, não é endereço de memoria, isso está errado. Sugiro que leia tambem as perguntas que linkei, pq essa informação da sua resposta nao está correta.

Comment: Sim. Ao imprimir um objeto da lista o metódo toString é chamado e esse mostra o "nome do objeto" que seria um identificador.

Comment: Não é um identificador, nem endereço de memória.